# How to import specific div in php file to another php file

Tags: php, html, include

I need a insert "**inner-header-bottom-region-about**" div to about.php file. No need to insert another divs to the about page. How can I insert this into the about.php file?

```
<div id="inner-header-bottom-region-about">
  <div id="header-bottom">
    </div>
  <div id="header-inner">
    
  </div>
</div>

<div id="inner-header-bottom-region-work">
  <div id="header-bottom">
    
  </div>
  <div id="header-inner">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code instead of image.

Comment: Put that div into its own PHP file which can then be separately included into both places where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new php file with only inner-header-bottom-region-about div and include this new php file where you want the div using php include property